# Find out the coordinates where a cell was clicked

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am stuck in a problem building my app in swift. Basically i have a tableview which displays data in a custom cell. now this cell is divided into two images ; one on left and one on right.

When the cell is clicked; the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is called however i want to find out which part of the cell was clicked; whether it was the right image or the left image.

One way to do this was to overwride the `touchesbegan` event of my custom cell class; i can get the coordinates of the touch that way and manually check whether the left image or the right image was selected; however this results in the d`idSelectRowAtIndexPath` event not getting fired.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInView(self)
    var xcoord = location.x
    touchPosition = xcoord
}
```

This code is what i tried to use in my custom cell class but i don't know now how to fire the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` event of the table in which this cell exists. I don't have any reference to that table too.

Here touchPosition is a global variable and i was trying to set it so that i can access it in my `didSelectrowAtIndexPath` method but it doesn't get fired.

Comment: connect an outlet to your tableView and delete the overrides

Comment: you can get the cell in didselect method using         var selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!

Comment: You have to call `super`.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus yes if i delete the overwrides i do get which cell is selected but how do i know whether the left image is selected or the right one?

Comment: @Amit89 I can. I do but i want to know whether the left image is selected in the cell or the right one.

Comment: @AaronBrager can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @UsmanAmjed Please read the docs for this method. If you want your touch event to go up the responder chain, call `super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)`.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `selected` property of UITableViewCell to `true` at the end of `touchesBegan`?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `selected` property of the cell inside your `touchesBegan` function should make the delegate call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

If that doesn't work, you can try this:

Create a `weak var tableView: UITableView?` in your custom cell class. Also add `var indexPath: NSIndexPath` to know the cell's index path in your `UITableViewCell`. Then when creating the cells, set `tableView` to your table view, and `indexPath` to its index path.

Now, you have a link to the table view's delegate. So, in your custom cell class `touchesBegan`, you can call `tableView?.delegate?.tableView?(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)`

Comment: But you wouldn't want to do this in `touchesBegan`. The user should be able to slide their finger off the view to cancel the touch, for example.

Comment: Oh, right. He can implement it in `touchesEnded` and compute if it is within some safe distance from the view just like in UIButton. For `touchesBegan` he can just check if which image was initially pressed, then `touchesEnded` would check if the touch location is still within the safe distance.

Comment: Come to think of it, wouldn't the `touch` functions get in the way of the scrolling of the table view?

Comment: Not if he calls `super`.